# Problem with Total differentiation

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

[image]

In the above figure, we assumed that u and v were independent variables. Now, we can make a deduction that 
u=g(x,y) and similarly v=h(x,y) ,where x and y are dependent variables. In such a situation, would it make any sense to have a meaning to the partial derivative of u w.r.t. x or y ( I mean, because x and y are dependent variables, if x changes ---> y has to). So, one cannot treat y as a constant and have a partial derivative w.r.t. x. Am I right ? If not, where did I go wrong ? What's the correct approach ?

Comment: Not sure whether i understand your question. I think x and y are independent. You cannot say they are dependent only because they have the same letters of variables u,v. For example, x=u+v, y=u-v, here doesn't mean that u=(x+y)/2, or you can rewrite x=s+t while y=u-v, they have no relation.